# NIFI - Process Multiple Files as a Group

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm very new to Apache NIFI so it's possible that this is already covered but most of the information I can find supports a slightly different use-case.

I've got a bunch of files that are posted to an FTP or whatever -- they're all associated with each other by filename:

```
ID_Part1.zip
ID_Attachments.zip
ID_Part2.zip
ID_Customizations.txt
ID.done
```

There are a variable number of files per logical processing group, some are mandatory, some are optional, and some may be unexpected. We know they're all associated based on their ID prefix and we'll know they're all delivered once a .done file exists.

What's an appropriate way, in NIFI parlance, to ensure that none of the files belonging to any given ID are processed until the .done file exists and that the processor that receives that group of file gets access to all of them?

Some of how the data splitting and segregating is done is still magical to me, but it'd be a catastrophic failure for my requirements if some processor happened to say see all of those files except ID_Customizations.txt and process them as a valid, but secretly incomplete, group.

Answer (score 0):

> What's an appropriate way, in NIFI parlance, to ensure that none of
>   the files belonging to any given ID are processed until the .done file
>   exists

In your GetFile or ListFile processor you can use the property "File Filter" to firstly retrieve your .done file.

> processor that receives that group of file gets access to all of them

in you .done flowfile you can use fetchFile processor to fetch all file of a target directory.

More info about theses processors :

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListFile/index.html

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.FetchFile/

Comment: Perhaps this is the part I'm not yet understanding -- wouldn't GetFile create each file it pulled as a separate FlowFile which could theoretically be processed independently by a different worker in a cluster or just a different iteration of the same processor?

Comment: each file will be pulled as different flowfile. I guess you will have to retrieve important information from each file in attribut to make a final process